# Rails production server not responding to internet requests

Tags: apache2, rails

I'm utterly at a loss here - I've had a rails 4 production server running for a couple of months.  Not long ago something happened in my network and my server stopped responding to all requests.  I've been monkeying around with it for a while now, and can't seem to restore service beyond my router.  Can anyone help we?

A few status:
  router has port 80 open (port forwarding)
  ubuntu 14.04 (firewall off)
  apache + passenger
  postgres database

I'm not sure what other bits of info would be useful, nor am I sure where the break down is happening..

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching in the wrong place, I traced it down to an external dns issue - it was pointed to an old ip.